# The normalisation map is a bi-Lipschitz map?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, singularity-theory

Let $X$ a reduced analytic space, $n: W \rightarrow X$ the normalisation map, $W$ the normalisation of $X$ and $S$ the singular set of $X$. When we restrict $n$ to $W\setminus n^{-1}(S)$, we know that $n$ is a biholomorphism onto $X\setminus S$.

Is true that $n$ restricted to $W\setminus n^{-1}(S)$ is a homeomorphism bi-Lipschitz onto $X\setminus S$?

Comment: This is a meaningless question until you specified metrics on the domain and the range and what you mean by "bi-Lipschitz": Do you want only local control on distances (for this any Riemannian metric would do) or also global?

Comment: Consider two embeddings $h:X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$ and $g:W \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$. Then, the metrics on the $W$ and $X$ are the euclidian metric of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. A map $f:A \rightarrow B$  is bi-Lipschitz when there exists a constant $c$ such that for all $x,y \in A$ we have $d_{B}(f(x),f(y)) \leq c.d_{A}(x,y)$, where $d_{A}$ and $d_{B}$ are the metrics on $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I found a counter example for this when $X$ and $W$ are not germs of analytic spaces, but I do not know if this is true when $X,W$ are germs of analytic spaces at $0$. Remembering, a germ $(X,0)$ of an analytic space is a class of equivalence given for: $(X,0)$ and $(Y,0)$ (here $Y$ is again an analytic space) are equivalent if there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $0$ such that $X \cap U = Y \cap U$.